# How to get product id in the article text (j2store)

Tags: php, articles, j2store

I want to somehow get the product id from j2store and display the main image of each product in the article section each product.

In **/templates/namira/html/com_content/article/default.php**
there are lines of codes which allow to display some content of the j2store product.

```
<div itemprop="articleBody">
    <?php echo $this->item->text; ?>
</div>
```

But how to alter this code to include also the main image of the product?
something like:

```
echo $this->product->j2store_product_id;
```

I want to include the j2store product class.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_j2store/helpers/j2store.php');
$product = F0FTable::getAnInstance('Product', 'J2StoreTable')->getClone();
if($product->get_product_by_source('com_content', $this->item->id)) {
        //return what you want for example      
        echo $product->j2store_product_id;
}
```